# Multiple AdminMiddleware Ambiguity

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple admin system: one is super admin and the other is normal admin, distinguished by `is_admin` attribute in users table.

And these two middlewares:
*SuperAdminMiddleware.php*

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if($request->user()->is_admin==1)
        {
           return $next($request);
        }
         return redirect('/login');    
    }
    else 
    {
      return redirect('/login');   
    }
}
```

and, *NormalAdminMiddleware.php*

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if($request->user()->is_admin==2)
        {
           return $next($request);
        }
         return redirect('/login');    
    }
    else 
    {
      return redirect('/login');   
    }
}
```

and in loginController:

```
protected function authenticated()
{
  if (auth()->user()->is_admin==1) {
    return redirect('/super-admin');
  } 

  else if(auth()->user()->is_admin==2){
    return redirect('/normal-admin'); 
  }

  else {
    return redirect('/home');
  }
}
```

Now, Delete and Read should be designed in such a way that super admin can delete and see all users details, while normal admin can only see their city's user.

```
id  name city   is_admin
1   Non  Maety  1
3   Pom  Lorey  2
4   Rom  Lorey  0
2   Yer  Easter 0
```

Non should be able to see all. while  Pom should see only id 3 and 4.

If i put show and delete routes under SuperAdminMiddleware, Normal Admin couldnot see their city's records.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware']], function () {
    Route::get('/show/{id}', 'MyController@show');      
    Route::post('/delete', 'MyController@delete');
  });
```

And if i put these routes under both SuperAdminMiddleware and NormalAddminMiddleware. NormalAdminMiddleware can also see other city's records.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['App\Http\Middleware\NormalAdminMiddleware']], function () {
        Route::get('/show/{id}', 'MyController@show');      
        Route::post('/delete', 'MyController@delete');
      });
```

How do i overcome this situation?

Comment: First As per your middleware condition, If you are using both, then any of the middleware fail for both superadmin and normaladmin, So both user can't access.
Route group should be separated for superadmin and normaladmin. Then from your controller you can pass where clause to achieve the output

Comment: At this moment you could simplify your middle and only use one check `is_admin > 0` Middleware is not the way to go to hide content / buttons or other actions based on admin level. I suggest you look into Gate/Policies https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization to check permissions for actions. Use your AdminMiddleware to check if the user is allowed to access the routes and check individual routes using gate/policy objects

Comment: @Ken gets a plus one. A super and normal user are best distinguished by the role they play and permissions they have. You could also consider ACL packages such as [entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) or [Sentinel](https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it with a policy:

```
class UserPolicy
{

    /**
     * Determine if the given user can be viewed by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User $account
     * @return bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, User $account)
    {
        switch($user->is_admin) {
            case 1:
                return true;
            case 2:
                return $user->city == $account->city;
            default:
            return 0;

        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the given user can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\User $account
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, User $account)
    {
        switch($user->is_admin) {
            case 1:
                return true;
            case 2:
                return $user->city == $account->city;
            default:
            return 0;

        }
    }
}
```

User would be the authenticated user model, account would be the user model that should be viewed.

After you registered your policy (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization#registering-policies) you can call it in the function of your controller like:

```
public function show(User $user) {
    $this->can('view', $user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your purpose clearly by reading the question. If you put your methods under SuperAdminMiddleware, normal admin should be rejected and redirect to '/login'. If you want to control the operation of admin, I think middleware can't solve the problem. As the previous answer, when operate the data of database, judge whether he is superAdmin or not.